# Storing objects in file instead of in memory

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, genetic-programming

I've created a genetic programming system in Python, but am having troubles related to memory limits. The problem is with storing all of the individuals in my population in memory. Currently, I store all individuals in memory, then reproduce the next generation's population, which then gets stored in to memory. This means that I have two populations worth of individuals loaded in memory. After some testing, I've found that I exceed the default 2GB application memory size for Windows fairly quickly.

Currently, I write out the entire population's individual trees to a file, which I can then load and recreate the population if I want. What I have been considering is instead of having all of the individuals loaded in memory, access individual information by pulling the individual from the file and only instantiating that single individual. From my understanding of Python's readline functionality, it should only load a single line from the file at a time, instead of the entire file. If I did this, I think I would be able to only store in memory the individuals that I was currently manipulating.

My question is, is there an underlining problem with doing this that I'm not seeing right now? I understand that because I am dealing with data on disk instead of in memory my performance is going to take a hit, but for this situation memory is more important than speed. Also I don't want to increase the allotted 2GB of memory given to Python programs.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't considered using a database?

Comment: Pulling an individual record from the file means reading through the file until you find the proper record. I highly recommend moving to a computer with a modern 64-bit environment and a reasonable amount of RAM. If you'd like to optimize your program anyway, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it currently works, consider asking on Code Review instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I considered it, but after each generation at least 95% of the individuals in the population are replaced. It didn't seem like using a database would be the right direction as data records only persist for a very short amount of time.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You're right, I would have to iterate through the file until I found the correct line. The computer I will be running this on is 64-bit, however, is restricted in terms of the amount of RAM available, and due to unknown tree sizes for my population I could potentially exceed physical RAM available, even if the application was given more than just 2GB. I don't think any code examples are necessary, as I'm asking more conceptually if writing population data to a file is a solution to reducing memory usage.

Comment: A MCVE might allow us to suggest a way of optimizing RAM usage without sacrificing performance.

Comment: Consider using [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) and an SSD. I have been using [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) for large datasets a lot (well, actually I use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` with memory mapped reading).

Comment: Furthering the point made by @Sumurai8 -- depending on how you've encoded your population there is a lot you can do to reduce memory overhead. For instance, an empty instance of a user defined class takes up 152 bytes (though objects with a small number of attributes don't use additional space). Add an extra 8 bytes per object if you're storing your objects in a list. Using `__slots__` you can get this overhead down to 16 bytes (plus the 8 for the space in the list). With `numpy` you can get the overhead down to 0 bytes. Though this requires some loss of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the RAM constraint, I'd change the population model from generational to ***steady state***.

The idea is to iteratively breed a new child or two, assess their fitness and then reintroduce them directly into the population itself, killing off some preexisting individuals to make room for them.

Steady state uses **half the memory** of a traditional genetic algorithm because there is only one population at a time.

Changing the implementation shouldn't be too hard, but you have to pay attention to premature convergence (i.e. tweaks parameters like mutation rate, tournament size...).

The ***island model*** is another / additional possibility: population is broken into separate sub-populations (demes). Demes send individuals to one another to help spread news of newly-discovered fit areas of the space.

Usually it's a *asynchronous* mechanism but you could use a *synchronous algorithm*, loading demes one by one, with a great reduction of the required memory resources.

---

Of course you can write the population to a file and you can load just the needed individuals. If you choose this approach, it's probably a good idea to compute a hash signature of individuals to optimize the identification / loading speed.

Anyway you should consider that, depending on the task your GP system is performing, you could register a massive performance hit.

Comment: I think steady state might be the direction I'll head in. So because you don't really have generations, do you need to flag each individual as having their fitness calculated or not, and then once per iteration loop calculate the false flagged individual's fitness, or just as soon as the individual is added to the population calculate their fitness?

Comment: @Tory If you use some form of elitism you immediately need the fitness (you have to compare the new individual with the one you would like to replace).

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that if you use Steady State, you would need to have some method to have the probability of the Fittest individuals to cross breed to be higher than the less fit individuals.

A couple of additional options you could think about are:

a) Use SQLLite.  (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).  This would have all of the performance advantages of using a database (probably more) plus the simplicity and ease-of-use of using a file.

b) There is a hybrid non-steady state model that allows to keep a large, unevaluated Polulation, size M and a "Survivor Set" of the fittest individuals size N, where M >> N.   Population is a Queue of Solution objects but SurvivorSet is a limited-size [Heap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) of "EvaluatedSolutions" (a Solution decorated with Fitness).  So, you keep taking Solutions from the General Population,  evaluating them, then placing them in the EvaluatedSolution Heap (sorted in descending order by fitness) and cropping the Top N elements.    That way, your memory consumption remains constant, but you have the concept of Elites built in.   This also allows to do cool tricks like "breeding" by using only the elite as the breeding population.